# How to deserialize json without index with json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Using json4s, what is best practice to deserialize JSON to Scala case class (without index-key)?

```
some.json
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "year": 2014
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "year": 2015
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "year": 2016
  }
}
```

`some case class
case class Foo(id: Int, year: Int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deserialize your json to corresponding scala data structure. In your case the type is `Map[Int, Foo]`. So extract this type first. The helping snippet is:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

implicit lazy val formats = DefaultFormats
val json =
  """
    |{
    |  "1": {
    |    "id": 1,
    |    "year": 2014
    |  },
    |  "2": {
    |    "id": 2,
    |    "year": 2015
    |  },
    |  "3": {
    |    "id": 3,
    |    "year": 2016
    |  }
    |}
  """.stripMargin
case class Foo(id: Int, year: Int)

val ast = parse(json)
val fooMap = ast.extract[Map[Int, Foo]]
```

Result:

```
Map(1 -> Foo(1,2014), 2 -> Foo(2,2015), 3 -> Foo(3,2016))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Map[String, Foo]`?